# C++ private polymorphic implementation design

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

This is a C++(11) question.
I have a object `Obj myObj` encapsulating an object `f` of type `MyType`.
Depending on runtime context, the object `f`should behave differently.

One natural way of implementing this would be for the class `Obj` to encapsulate a pointer to an abstract base class `MyType`, which would, depending on the context point to different (public) child of `MyType`, such as `MyType1`, `MyType2`, etc.

However, I'm not very keen on `Obj` "suffering" the consequences of `MyType` being polymorphic, i.e. having to deal with a **pointer**. In particular, if I make it a `std::unique_ptr<MyType>`, it implies that `Obj` can either not be copied or that one needs to give it a proper copy constructor that deals with copying MyType ressources.

In my opinion, `MyType` being polymorphic shouldn't be `Obj`'s problem.

I came with the following classes. Essentially the idea is to hide the pointer within `MyType`private attributes. In addition my second question concerns the fact that concrete implementations of `MyTypeImpl` may share some code shouldn't be repeated. I've put that in a class from which concrete implementations privately inherit.

I'm curious what more expert developers than me would think about it. Is it too heavy "just to hide the pointer"? Is there a better way to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


// a "standard" implementation of MyType
class MyTypeImpl
{
    public:        
        virtual double operator()(double a) = 0;
        virtual int implType() const = 0;
        virtual void complexStuff() const = 0;
};



// some internal stuff common to all implementations
class MyTypeImplInternals
{
protected:    
    MyTypeImplInternals(int value):factor_{value}{}
    int factor_;
    void longCommonFunction() const{ std::cout << "I'm doing complex stuff common to all interfaces " << factor_ << "\n" ;}
};


// one specific implementation
class MyTypeImpl1: public MyTypeImpl, private MyTypeImplInternals
{
    public:
        MyTypeImpl1(int factor):MyTypeImplInternals{factor}{};

        virtual double operator()(double a) override {return factor_*a;} 
        virtual int implType() const override {return 1;}
        virtual void complexStuff() const override { longCommonFunction(); }
};


// a second implementation
class MyTypeImpl2: public MyTypeImpl, private MyTypeImplInternals
{
    public:
        MyTypeImpl2(int factor):MyTypeImplInternals{factor}{};
        virtual double operator()(double a) override {return factor_*a;} 
        virtual int implType() const override {return 2;}
        virtual void complexStuff() const override { longCommonFunction(); }
};



class MyTypeImplFactory
{
    public:
    static std::unique_ptr<MyTypeImpl>createMyTypeImpl(int implementationType)
    {        
        switch(implementationType)
        {
            case 1:            
              return std::unique_ptr<MyTypeImpl> (new MyTypeImpl1(12));

             case 2:
                return std::unique_ptr<MyTypeImpl> (new MyTypeImpl2(22));

            default:
                throw std::runtime_error("implementation does not exist...\n");
                return nullptr;
        }
    }
};



// my type
class MyType
{
    public:

        MyType(int implementationType)
        {
            implPtr_ = MyTypeImplFactory::createMyTypeImpl(implementationType);   
        }

        MyType(MyType const& source)
        : implPtr_{ MyTypeImplFactory::createMyTypeImpl(source.implType()) }
        {
        }


        double operator()(double a){return (*implPtr_)(a);}  
        int implType() const {return implPtr_->implType();}
        void complexStuff() const {implPtr_->complexStuff();}


    private:
        std::unique_ptr<MyTypeImpl> implPtr_;
};








class Obj
{
 private:
    MyType f;

public:
    Obj(int dim):f{dim}{}    
    Obj(Obj&& sourceToMove) = default;
    Obj(Obj const& source) = default;

    void doStuff() {std::cout << "I'm doing stuff()  " << f(2) << std::endl; f.complexStuff();}
};







int main()
{
 Obj myObj{1}, myObj2{2};

 myObj.doStuff();
 myObj2.doStuff();

 Obj myObj3{std::move(myObj2)}; // myObj2 now dead
 Obj myObj4{myObj}; 

 myObj3.doStuff();
 myObj4.doStuff();

}
```

link to online compiler  : http://cpp.sh/8rhyy

Here the implementations are very dumb ones to serve as an example. An application for this design could be for instance a `Solver` (`Obj`) that solves some kind of physics `Equation` (`MyType`) which exact definition depends on the dimensionality of the problem, equation in 1D space is not the same as in 2D or in 3D. `Solver`'s code would be completely independent on `Equation`'s dimensionality and also wouldn't have to deal with a pointer. `Equation` would hide its 1D, 2D, or 3D implementation from outside's world.

(was originally a post on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139787/encapsulated-polymorphism) that was put on Hold because to abstract)

Comment: These are really two different problems, and as such should be two separate SO questions (each with cut-down example code, to make it easier to extract the essence of the question).  As it stands, this is a ton of code.

Comment: Does `Obj` actually *need* to be copyable?

Comment: Standard type-erasure techniques could be used for `MyType`. As an example from the standard library, consider `std::function`: It's copyable and value-like, but manages runtime-determined dispatch implementations.

Comment: searching in internet I found my code looks like the "Pimpl" pattern. The only difference would be that here the Pimpl pointer is polymorphic. Is that really to much code?

Comment: Implement your owm smart pointer with polymorphic copy semantic.

Comment: What do you mean  "I'm not very keen on Obj "suffering" the consequences of MyType being polymorphic"? And what does that have to do with using unique_ptr? Also "Essentially the idea is to hide the pointer within MyType private attributes." What is the pointer _within_ MyType? You have only spoken about a pointer _to_ MyType so far.

Comment: If I didn't hide the pointer, I'd have to have `Obj` to hold that pointer (whatever kind of pointer) for its attribute `f`to be polymorphic. `Obj`'s code would then have to explicitly dereference the pointer, etc. I see no reason why it should be that way. `MyType`'s behavior is polymorphic, that's `MyType`'s own problem.

Comment: For the copy constructor, I would use a clone method.

Comment: for which class ? MyType ? why ? since I can define my own copy constructor, can you explain what'd be the advantage of a clone method?

Comment: @MCF: For `MyType`. It would allow to get rid of `MyTypeImpl::implType()`, and would allow to handle correctly internal state of the derived class (as a random engine for example).

Answer (score -1):

This proposed class design appears to have an obvious problem. The polymorphic type is referenced by a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyTypeImpl> implPtr_;
```

`Obj`'s default copy constructor, and assignment operator will end up transferring the held pointer to the new object, leaving the `std::unique_ptr` in the original object staring at a `nullptr`. Not good.

At the bare minimum this should be either a `std::shared_ptr`, or `Obj`'s copy constructor and assignment operator will need to instantiate a new `implPtr_`.  Note that with the easy `std::shared_ptr` fix the result of the copy constructor and an assignment operator is having multiple instances of `Obj` referencing the same instance of `MyTypeImpl`, which may or may not be an issue.

A much simpler class design is simply have `MyTypeImpl1` and `MyTypeImpl2` be subclasses of `Obj`, implementing the required polymorphic behavior.

Comment: not sure I understand why Obj copy constructor would lead to problems. On the contrary, in my opinion, Obj default copy ctor will call memberwise copy ctors, i.e. wil call MyType copy cosntructor, which I defined to allocate a new `ImplPtr_`using the factory.

Comment: Maybe you should review what `std::unique_ptr`'s copy constructor does. That should clear things up.

Comment: I know unique_ptr only has move ctor and can't be copied. When it is moved it transfers ownership and is set to nullptr OK. But in this case Obj copy ctor calls MyType copy constructor which I have defined and I think the original unique_ptr is never moved. No? I've checked in the online code to look at the address held by the source pointer and the new one, both are not null and are different... What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: MyType(MyType const& source)
        : implPtr_{ MyTypeImplFactory::createMyTypeImpl(source.implType()) }
        {
        }

Answer (score -2):

I just refactored your codes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


// !abstraction
class MyType
{
    public:        
        virtual double operator()(double a) = 0;
        virtual int implType() const = 0;
        virtual void complexStuff() const = 0;
};

// !!MyTypeImplInternals could be a super class of MyTypeImpl* if it has properties(such as factor_) or just some static functions.
class MyTypeImplInternals
{
public:    
    MyTypeImplInternals(int value):factor_{value}{}
    int factor_;
    void longCommonFunction() const{ std::cout << "I'm doing complex stuff common to all interfaces " << factor_ << "\n" ;}
};

// one specific implementation
class MyTypeImpl1: public MyType
{
    MyTypeImplInternals internal_;
    public:
        MyTypeImpl1(int factor):internal_{factor}{};

        virtual double operator()(double a) override {return internal_.factor_*a;} 
        virtual int implType() const override {return 1;}
        virtual void complexStuff() const override { internal_.longCommonFunction(); }
};

// a second implementation
class MyTypeImpl2: public MyType
{
    MyTypeImplInternals internal_;
    public:
        MyTypeImpl2(int factor):internal_{factor}{};
        virtual double operator()(double a) override {return internal_.factor_*a;} 
        virtual int implType() const override {return 2;}
        virtual void complexStuff() const override { internal_.longCommonFunction(); }
};

std::unique_ptr<MyType> createMyType(int implementationType)
{        
    switch(implementationType)
    {
        case 1:            
          return std::unique_ptr<MyType> (new MyTypeImpl1(12));

         case 2:
            return std::unique_ptr<MyType> (new MyTypeImpl2(22));

        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("implementation does not exist...\n");
            return nullptr;
    }
}

class Obj
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<MyType> f_;

public:
    Obj(int dim):f_(createMyType(dim)){}    
    Obj(Obj&& sourceToMove) : f_(std::move(sourceToMove.f_)) {}
    Obj(Obj const& source) : f_(createMyType(source.f_->implType())) {}

    void doStuff() {std::cout << "I'm doing stuff()  " << (*f_)(2) << std::endl; f_->complexStuff();}
};

int main()
{
 Obj myObj{1}, myObj2{2};

 myObj.doStuff();
 myObj2.doStuff();

 Obj myObj3{std::move(myObj2)}; // myObj2 now dead
 Obj myObj4{myObj};  //!!Bad idea to share an implementation to more Objs.

 myObj3.doStuff();
 myObj4.doStuff();

}
```

Comment: What specific changes did you make, and why? How is this "refactoring" better than the original? As it stands, this is a non-answer.

Comment: you basically have got rid of the private pointer to the abstract implementation in MyType and put a `unique_ptr<MyType>` into `Obj`. This is what I said at the beginning of my post the "natural" way to do. I prefer `Obj`'s code not to *have to* deal with pointer *just* because MyType is polymorphic

Comment: The copy constructor of MyType is just creating a MyTypeImpl with the same type. It is confused that you implement the copy constructor but copy nothing. I think Obj should not be copied if it isn't a pure data class like a **struct** in C. The real problem is the wrong usage of Obj but the polymorphism.

Comment: Well... if there would be other attributes in `MyType` I'd copy them, but here there's (for this simplified example) only the unique_ptr, which can't be copied... so I have to create another from the factory... you'll notice that I'm not creating it from nowhere, I'm using the informations hold by `sourceToMove` to do that.

From `Obj`'s perspective, `MyType` is just a type, that can be copied, why should `Obj` not be allowed to be copied then?

Comment: Syntactically, every property in an object is copiable except you disallow it. It is difficult to decide without a context. Considering your codes, I think the point is to write fewer codes to make `Obj` copiable. So, a copy constructor is enough. More abstraction makes no sense.

Comment: Glad to discuss it here with you guys.